# When iterating through file.lines() how can I get the next line coming

Tags: rust

I'm iterating through a file like this:

```rust
for line in file.lines() {
    if line == something {
        println!("{}", line);
    }
}
```

This works great, but how can I get the line that's coming in the next iteration of the loop?

something like this would be great:

```rust
for line in file.lines() {
    if line == something {
        println!("{}", line);
        line.next();
        println!("{}", line); // This would be the next line coming in the file
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to advance the iterator? That is, the line after will be the same line or the line after the `next()`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes I want to advance the iterator. To get the next line coming up.

Comment: You can store the current line until next iteration, then do your work as if the last is the current and the current is the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `for` with [`while let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/while_let.html):

```rust
let mut lines = file.lines();
while let Some(line) = lines.next() {
    if line == something {
        println!("{}", line);
        let new_line = lines.next().unwrap();
        println!("{}", new_line);
    }
}
```